# Bind JButton text to property

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am Swing novice. I made a small app using JTree, JCheckBox, JList and JButton. I am using the associated model classes to store the presentation state. Works fine, except for the JButton. I'd like to update the button's text according to a property of my model. Basically, it will change from log in/to log off whether the user is currently logged in. Unfortunatly, I can't find a setText method in the ButtonModel interface. Can anybody tell me how to do this ?

Thanks. PW.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `JButton` you can use an `Action` as your model. The `Action` interface defines keys which are used by the `JButton` to retrieve its state from the `Action`, including one for the text: `Action.NAME`

If you look at the source code, the constructor with the `Action` (or simply the `setAction` method) uses more information from the `Action` then what can be retrieved from a `ButtonModel`. Same for other constructors, e.g.

```
public JButton(String text, Icon icon) {
    // Create the model
    setModel(new DefaultButtonModel());

    // initialize
    init(text, icon);
}
```

So it seems that you are correct in your assessment that the `ButtonModel` does not contain all information used to visualize a typical `JButton`

Comment: are you meaning [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html)